# Filtering on date in pivot table based on power pivot gives the wrong filter context when date relationship is inactive

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerpivot, dax

I have a table `employees` that stores `dateStarted` and `dateQuit` in two columns.

This table is part of a Power Pivot model and is connected to a `dimDates` table.

I have created pivot tables based on this Power Pivot model.

When I show the count of `dateStarted` in the table is works as expected. It shows how many people started in each month.

When I show the count of `dateQuit` in the table it seems to still use the active relationship date context, that between `dimDates[Date]` and `employees[dateStarted]`.

Can I create a measure for count `dateQuit` that does not use the relationship between `dimDates[Date]` and `employees[dateStarted]`?

Comment: Do you need to have role-palying dimensions? i.e. DateStarted and DateQuit dimensions that are both based on your dimDates table, and then each column references the relevant dimension. These can be implemented as views on your dimDates table and imported into your Powerpivot model.

Comment: Do you have more information about how to use views as an alternative solution for this problem? That would definitely be a possible solution

Comment: Create 2 views. One called DimDatesStarted and another called DimDatesQuit. They are both based on your DimDates table. Import these 2 views into your PowerPivot model. Then relate each of your columns to the respective view. That should solve your problem. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would solve the problem. I'll read up on views. Is that considered good/best practice for these kinds of issues? You're welcome to suggest your idea as a soution, since it does solve my problem.

Comment: Yes it is certainly good practice. Google role playing dimensions to find out more. I will post this as an answer. Thanks. Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 views. One called DimDatesStarted and another called DimDatesQuit. They are both based on your DimDates table. Import these 2 views into your PowerPivot model. Then relate each of your columns to the respective view. That should solve your problem. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use something like this:

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(employees), 
           USERELATIONSHIP(employees[dateQuit], dimDates[Date])
           )
```

For this to work the inactive relationship has to be in place.